# android application is not able to access GPRS in dual sim phon

Tags: android

I am using `org.apache.http` in my app to connect with internet but when I am running my app in Samsung galaxy duos y gt-1602, then it is not able to use Sim GPRS while it is running properly with WiFi.

Can anyone suggest me what could be the problem or possible solution.

Comment: If there is WiFi Connectivity, I am pretty sure that GPRS wont be used by the system.

Comment: yes but when i turn off WiFi then its not working while GPRS is still working

Answer (score 0):

Is there any lines of code related to **Network connectivity type** in your pgm?

Following if a simple method to detect connectivity.

```
    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null) 
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null) 
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {

                  Log.d("Connectivity", "info:"+info[i]);//Here you can check network info if available

                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }
              }

      }
      return false;
}
```

Comment: yes i have this method and it returns true but still I am not able to send my data to server. and it is not giving any exception in first execution but in second execution it gives invalid use of SingalClieanConnManager.   please help me

Comment: I think its related to your coding.